# A best way to protect entity field in Symfony forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In my Symfony2 app there are users end hotels, for each user it's esay to define his hotels.

In order to list user's hotels I use

```
class HotelVoter implements VoterInterface
```

which works fine.

In application there are forms of **Order** to a **Hotel** *(so order.hotel_id = hotel.id)*. For this reason there is a field **Hotel** in **Order's** form:

```
$builder->add('hotel', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Hotel',
    'property' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => ...,
    ...
));
```

The problem is that form shows me all existing hotels regardless security voter.

What is the best way to leverage my existing voter. I don't feel like using *query_builder* for this aim.

Thanks

Comment: rather than asking the voter if the user has access to each and every hotel, I would say query builder and form event is the way to go. That way you only fetch the hotels that the user has access to.

Comment: Yes, you are right but my forms are general and Orders - Hotels is only a particular case. I will use **query_builder** but I would like to have another level of protection.